# Supabase SQL query function getting error 'structure of query does not match function result type'

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I created a SQL query function for fetch projects from table but I am getting error

> structure of query does not match function result type

Here's the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_projects(uid uuid, key text) RETURNS setof projects AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT id as pid, pgp_sym_decrypt(title::bytea, key) as title, pgp_sym_decrypt(description::bytea, key) as description, created_at, user_id from public.projects where user_id = uid;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

If I run single query in Supabase SQL query it returns rows

```
SELECT 
    id as pid, 
    pgp_sym_decrypt(title::bytea, key) as title,    
    pgp_sym_decrypt(description::bytea, key) as description, 
    created_at, user_id 
FROM
    public.projects 
WHERE
    user_id = uid
```